# MAUI Blazor authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, maui

Maybe I'm missing something but in the file `MauiProgram.cs` the `builder.Build()` return an object of type `MauiApp` and this does not contain the extension methods `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()` that normaly in Blazor/asp net core projects you would find for `IApplicationBuilder`.
So do I need to use the WebAuthenticator as explained here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-essentials-1-7-and-introducing-net-maui-essentials/
in order to archieve the same result?

Comment: Ended up extending AuthenticationStateProvider and making a custom one...

Comment: Would you be willing to share your code or even better a working example on github?

Comment: @Duken.Jr sure, i can make a new working example but it will take me a while. I can't share the code i have in my job project. If you need any suggestion in the mean while tell me.

Answer (score 0):

As OP stated, he extended AuthenticationStateProvider and making a custom one..

I added an example of this here:

[AuthenticationStateProvider example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72636921/7810803)

Comment: don't point to your own answer. Mark the question as duplicate if they are same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).